# SQL to select a table through a generic relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server

In a relational database I have three tables. Using SQL Server.

```
person(id, type)
student(id, person_id, type, student specific fields)
teacher(id, person_id, type, teacher specific fields)
```

Student and teacher are both people, therefore a student will have a record in both the person and student tables, as will the teacher. Student and teacher have foreign keys to person. Student and teacher have different field definitions therefore a union will NOT work.

Now I have the person's id and depending on whether the person is a student or teacher I would like to select * from the relevant table (not person).

For example, if the person is a student I would like my query to select the student table.

I can think of a few inefficient methods but I am looking for the optimum one.

Comment: What columns do you want to return?  This kind of query cannot be constructed properly without knowing that.

Comment: If Student and Teacher 'are' Persons (i.e. inherit Person) then you probably don't need a new surrogate key - they can continue to use the `person(id)` key

Comment: You haven't indicated which database system you're using, but in standard SQL, any particular query will only reference specific tables, and the "shape" of the result set (meaning, the columns, and specifically the name and type of each column) is fixed.

Comment: @RBarryYoung The columns in teacher and student will be different, therefore your below comment is correct, a union will not work.

Comment: @nonnb Are you getting at the fact that I do not need the id in student and teacher because I can use person_id as the primary key?

Comment: @StephenH then your question text should be edited to reflect that.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever SQL Server. So what you are saying is that I need to define the specific table in the SQL? Would this only be solved via application code?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a UNION

```
 SELECT student.* 
 FROM student
 WHERE person_id= @id
 UNION
 SELECT teacher.* 
 FROM teacher
 WHERE person_id= @id
```

Comment: Will only work if the student and teacher tables have the same column definitions

Answer (score 1):

```
if exists(select person_id from student where person_id = @id)
select * from student where person_id = @id
else
if exists(select person_id from teacher where person_id = @id)
select * from teacher where person_id = @id
```

Comment: In the future I will have more people in the system like principle and district manager. How efficient do you think this approach will be?

Answer (score 1):

If your RDBMS is `SQLServer`, then I would abstract a view along the lines of podiluska's union, mapping out specific fields in Student and Teacher to common names, and padding with NULLs where no mapping is possible

And assuming that Students and Teachers inherit from person (i.e. both are 0..1 to 1 with Person), then they can share the same primary key, i.e. no need for new surrogates keys on Teacher and Student.

I've assumed that `person.type` determines whether the person is a Student(S) or Teacher(T).

```
CREATE VIEW SubClassesOfPerson AS
   SELECT p.id as PersonId, 
          p.name as PersonName, 
          p.OtherBaseFieldsHere, 
          s.SomeStudentSpecificField AS MappedField1,
          s.SomeStudentSpecificFieldX AS MappedFieldX,
          s.SomeStudentSpecificField as MappedFieldForStudentOnly,
          NULL as MappedFieldForTeacherOnly -- Pad this because it can't be mapped
   FROM person p 
      INNER JOIN student s
      on s.person_id = p.id AND p.type = 'S'

   UNION

   SELECT p.id as PersonId, 
          p.name as PersonName, 
          p.OtherBaseFieldsHere, 
          t.SomeTeacherSpecificField AS MappedField1,
          t.SomeTeacherSpecificFieldX AS MappedFieldX,
          NULL as MappedFieldForStudentOnly,  -- Pad this because it can't be mapped
          t.SomeTeacherSpecificField as MappedFieldForTeacherOnly
   FROM person p 
      INNER JOIN teacher t
      on t.person_id = p.id AND p.type = 'T'
```